# Login forbidden after upgrading Meteor version 2.2 to 2.4

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts, meteor-useraccounts

Meteor version: **2.4**
Node version: **14.x**

After upgrading **Meteor version** **2.2** to **2.4** I face some issues. In the project, I used **useraccounts:core** and connected with that some other dependencies. After the upgrade my login design changed and when I try to log in it will show me the **“Login forbidden”** error. I am attaching the previous login design after upgrading the design.

PREVIOUS DESIGN:

[image]

CURRENT DESIGN:

[image]

Now if I use email rather than username it will be logged in but the home screen is blank. I am sure that logged in successfully because in local storage the desired details are stored.

Comment: Did you update the Meteor version directly from 2.2 to 2.4? If yes, take a look in the Changelog documentation because there are some required steps to do. See https://docs.meteor.com/changelog#v2320210624 . My advice is take a look in each version about the breaking changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same issue for **2.2 to 2.3**, So I did the below steps to solve this issue. I tried 2 ways where 1st point is wrong.

**1. Remove the packages and then update:**

- I got multiple package errors while updating 2.2 to 2.3 because in 2.3 is major change happened. So I checked the conflicts packages and removed those package dependencies.
- Then I pass the update command in my project:

```
meteor update --release 2.3
```

- It will update the version but is not able to start a project. So I add one by one removed dependencies and then try again. But not worth it.

**2. Understand the issue and Fork it(Best and easy way):**

- This is the perfect and clear way to solve this issue. I checked the errors and understood which package having an issue while updating. I checked the root package dependency and checked that particular package in the [atmosphere.js](https://atmospherejs.com/).
- Then I fork a package and remove the .git folder.
- Then place that new folder inside of our projects repo and place it inside the package/ folder.
- So now it will take that dependency from your local repository.
- Now try the update command again:

```
meteor update --release 2.3
```

- If you see the same error then do the same process for another package.

Using the 2nd step I can solve this issue very easily.